# Reading values from user in C#

Tags: java, c#, input

This code works fine, if the user enters the numbers in separate lines
i.e.
10
12
Result is : 22

However, when I try to input this there is an error.
10 12

Now, I know `console.readline()` reads the entire line, and obviously the space isn't an `int` and so I get the error. However, when I used to code in C, there was `scanf` function, which by simply specifying the datatype to expect from user, could run for both the cases. Also, I think JAVA's `scanner.nextInt()` would have not allowed such troubles. Is there any simple way to ask c# to read data separated by spaces, or lines in the same manner? This is the only reason why I never used c# in coding competitions. I simply don't understand how to solve this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
 class Program
 {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result=0,a, b;
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        result = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Seems you need `String.Split` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well that would work if the user enters inputs in the same line.However he might write the inputs in seperate lines.and so my string.split would lead to an error in the latter case because it wouldn't find any other int in the same line

Comment: You can use `Regex` then to extract numbers from your `String`

Comment: Modified my answer please check it out if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example where extract the number(s) from the string with `Regex`

```
            string input = "There are 4 numbers in this string: 40, 30, and 10.";
            // Split on one or more non-digit characters.
            string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
            foreach (string value in numbers)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    int i = int.Parse(value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If the user enters each integer in a seperate line your "parse element 1" won't work. I am looking for somethhing that's handles both types of user input

Comment: In your post you ask `.Is there any simple way to ask c# to read data seperated by spaces or lines ` what is the input and output you expect?